# WPF DataGrid - Bind to collection of 'cells'

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm trying to figure out how to bind the datasource of a DataGrid to an ObservableCollection of 'cells'.  In particular, I have an ObservableCollection that holds instances of the following class:

```
public class Option : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Option()
    {
    }

    // +-+- Static Information +-+-
    public double spread = 0;        
    public double strike = 0;        
    public int daysToExpiry = 0;
    public int put_call; // 0 = Call, 1 = Put

    // Ticker References
    public string fullTicker = "";
    public string underlyingTicker = "";

    //+-+-Properties used in Event Handlers+-+-//
    private double price = 0;
    public double Price
    {
        get { return price; }
        set
        {
            price = value; 
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Price");
        }
    }

    //+-+-+-+- Propoerty Changed Event & Hander +-+-+-+-+-//
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
}
```

On my DataGrid, I want to display these classes (I'm using TemplateColumns the Price and the 'strike' variables in each cell) such that they are grouped by "underlyingTicker" [which is a 4 character string] and by "spread" [which takes on 1 of 6 possible values defined in the background coding].

Currently, when I bind the DataGrid's DataContext to the ObservableCollection, it shows each 'Option' as a row - and I can't figure out how to specify what to group the  pairs on...

This is what my datagrid looks like now:
[image]

Thanks a lot - kcross!

Comment: what's your DataGrid's ItemSource={Binding ...} look like, as well at least one code sample of you column and it's binding? Also what exaclty do you mean by:" and I can't figure out how to specify what to group the pairs on"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Dtex I do not entirely understand what you want to do. But I tried to make a simplification that hopefully will get you started.
You have to pass the `DataGrid`an `IEnumerable`(preferably an `ObserrvableCollection`) of objects. The individual objects will translate to rows, the properties of these objects will translate to the column headers.

So if you want the column headers to represent multiples of the standard deviation (right?) you will have to create an object that has these multiples as properties. The resulting cells will contain the `Option` classes. To represent these you will have to define a DataTemplate or override the ToString() function. I think you did the former judging from your example.

The code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
namespace DataGridSpike
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private List<Option> _unsortedOptions;
        private ObservableCollection<OptionRow> _groupedOptions;

        public ObservableCollection<OptionRow> GroupedOptions
        {
            get { return _groupedOptions; }
            set { _groupedOptions = value; }
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            var rnd=new Random();
            InitializeComponent();

            //Generate some random data
            _unsortedOptions=new List<Option>();
            for(int element=0;element<50;element++)
            {
                double column=rnd.Next(-2,3);
                int row=rnd.Next(0,9);

                _unsortedOptions.Add(new Option { ColumnDefiningValue = column, RowDefiningValue = row });
            }

            //Prepare the data for the DataGrid
            //group and sort
            var rows = from option in _unsortedOptions
                       orderby option.ColumnDefiningValue
                       group option by option.RowDefiningValue into optionRow
                       orderby optionRow.Key ascending
                       select optionRow;

            //convert to ObservableCollection
            _groupedOptions = new ObservableCollection<OptionRow>();
            foreach (var groupedOptionRow in rows)
            {
                var groupedRow = new OptionRow(groupedOptionRow);
                _groupedOptions.Add(groupedRow);
            }

            //bind the ObservableCollection to the DataGrid
            DataContext = GroupedOptions;
        }
    }

    public class OptionRow
    {
        private List<Option> _options;

        public OptionRow(IEnumerable<Option> options)
        {
            _options = options.ToList();
        }

        public Option Minus2
        {
            get
            {
                return (from option in _options
                       where option.ColumnDefiningValue == -2
                       select option).FirstOrDefault();
            }
        }
        public Option Minus1
        {
            get
            {
                return (from option in _options
                        where option.ColumnDefiningValue == -1
                        select option).FirstOrDefault();
            }
        }
        public Option Zero
        {
            get
            {
                return (from option in _options
                        where option.ColumnDefiningValue == 0
                        select option).FirstOrDefault();
            }
        }
        public Option Plus1
        {
            get
            {
                return (from option in _options
                        where option.ColumnDefiningValue == 1
                        select option).FirstOrDefault();
            }
        }
        public Option Plus2
        {
            get
            {
                return (from option in _options
                        where option.ColumnDefiningValue == 2
                        select option).FirstOrDefault();
            }
        }
    }

    public class Option:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("{0}-{1}", RowDefiningValue.ToString(),ColumnDefiningValue.ToString());
        }

        private double _columnDefiningValue;
        public double ColumnDefiningValue
        {
            get{return _columnDefiningValue;}
            set{_columnDefiningValue = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ColumndDefiningValue");
            }
        }

        private int _rowDefiningValue;
        public int RowDefiningValue
        {
            get{return _rowDefiningValue;}
            set{_rowDefiningValue = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("RowDefiningValue");
            }
        }

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged!=null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
}
```

The XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="DataGridSpike.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```